# Using VIM to find files in project

Tags: vim

I'm using VIM as my primary code editor for Laravel projects.  While I'm in VIM, I want to search for a file that I can open up as a `tabnew` or as a new `vsplit` pane.  I was told there's a [find command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:find). So I tried something like this:

```
:find ~/development.project1.com/ -name *Controller.php
```

But that only gave me the error `E345: Can't find file "/var/www/development.project1.com/ -name *Controller.php" in path`

What did I do wrong?  How can I quickly search for other files in VIM and open them up as a `tabnew` or as a new `vsplit` pane?

Comment: You linked to a doc (a good one) but where is option `-name` in the doc?

Answer (score 5):

The vim `find` command is not the same as the unix `find` command. To find out what `find` does, use the online help!

```
:h find
```

This will give you an answer:

```
:fin[d][!] [++opt] [+cmd] {file}                                                                                                                
Find {file} in 'path' and then :edit it.
```

In other words, `:find` is like `:edit` but looks in your `path` instead of just the current directory. Note that the vim `path` is not the same as the operating system shell variable `PATH`. You can find out what is in your `path` with

```
set path?
```

Most likely you don't have every subdirectory of your project in your path (or in your PATH). Neither should you.

If you want to edit a file with a name ending in Controller.php, a simple solution to search through every subdirectory is to specify `**` before the filename to wildcard-match against every subdirectory:

```
:e **/*Controller.php
```

Note that doing the above will only open the first file matching the wildcards. If there are several matching files, and that wasn't the file you wanted, no luck.

If you want to choose a file among several matches, and don't want to use plugins, you can read a list using the unix file command

```
:r! find . -name \*Controller.php
```

You will end up with a buffer with a list of files. To open one of the files, move the cursor above the file name, and use the `gf` command to open it.

While not really an answer to your question, with vanilla vim, there's `wildmode` command line completion. If `wildmode` is enabled, vim will complete filenames when you open a new file with `:e`.

Finally, there are lots of different fuzzy finder plugins for vim. If you don't need windows, I recommend fzf.

Answer (score 1):

`vim find` and `find` command are different as noted. Perhaps, you might like [ctrlp](https://github.com/ctrlpvim).

But a easier vanilla vim replacement is to go to the folder which contains your files and in `vim`

```
  :set path+=**
  :find file_name
```

This will find and edit `file_name`. Nice thing of this is that it can auto-complete the file name but this will not be in split or tab.

Comment: Actually, with path set correctly, I rarely need the double-star.